# Is it possible to skip chosen parameters from cookiecutter.json?

Tags: python, cookiecutter

I'm wondering, if it's possible to skip prompt for chosen parameters in `cookiecutter.json` based on value of other parameter? For example for `cookiecutter.json`:

```
{
  "ask_for_more": ["y", "n"],
  "some_parameter": "test"
}
```

I'd like to skip prompt for `some_parameter` if the answer to `ask_for_more` was `n`.

Is it possible ?

Comment: What prompt are you talking about? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm talking about prompt for parameters during generating "project" from cookiecutter template.

Comment: Were you able to find something useful for this?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, it is not possible to do it directly via the cookiecutter.json
I think even with pre-gen hook it might not be possible as the cookiecutter jinja templating executes regardless of the if/else python conditions.

There are however lots of  PR's and discussions to add this feature. See these links:

Closed threads:
https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/issues/881
https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/issues/913

Open threads:
https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/pull/1645
https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/issues/1438